# How to convert Js.Json.t to Js.t('a)?

Tags: reason, bucklescript, bs-json

I have encoded an object via bs-json and want to send it as a data via post using bs-axios.

```ml
  33 │ let createTest = (p: Data.toBuyListItem) => inst->Instance.postData("/
       test", p |> Data.encodeToBuyListItem);
...
  This has type:
    Js.Json.t (defined as Js.Json.t)
  But somewhere wanted:
    Js.t('a)
```

`p |> Data.encodeToBuyListItem` is red. How to use the `Js.Json.t` value as data for a post request?

Edit:

Well, this works:

```ml
let createTest = (p: Data.toBuyListItem) => inst->Instance.postData("/test", [%raw "p"]);
```

but I would prefer a non-hacky solution (preferably using bs-json, since I am using that for decoding JSON)...

Comment: Why have you encoded it as `Js.Json.t` if that's not what you actually need? You could instead just create a `Js.t` object directly.

Comment: @glennsl Well, I am using bs-json for decoding, so I thought I should use it for encoding as well (I only followed the encoding example). It's also recommended in bucklescript docs and I don't really know how to use `Js.t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to safely convert a `Js.Json.t` to `Js.t`, as the latter represents a JavaScript object, and JSON doesn't just represent objects. But `bs-axios` seems to throw safety out the window anyway, so you could just cast it unsafely:

```
external jsonToObjects : Js.Json.t => Js.t({..}) = "%identity";
```

`%identity` is a general mechanism that can be used to cast between any two types, so this is as unsafe as it gets with regards to typing. You're basically saying "Look away while I swap these things around and trust me, I know what I'm doing". So make sure you do.

Another alternative is to create a `Js.t` object directly. Reason has built-in syntax for that, so it's pretty easy:

```
let obj = {
  "data": someData
};
```

`someData` here can be any value, even a `Js.Json.t` value, but that also means you can pass in values that aren't serializable, which `Js.Json.t` protects you against.

Given that the `bs-axios` API is inherently unsafe there's a minor safety trade-off here, but I think whichever is easiest will do fine.